# Upgrading from ubuntu-16.04 I get "The system is running in low-graphics mode"

Tags: unity, root

I want sometimes to be able to login as root into the Unity desktop manager.
I made a fresh install of ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64 and in order to be able to login as root added the line:
greeter-show-manual-login=true
to
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
This leads to that I can't login to the desktop at all and I am only given the message "The system is running in low-graphics mode". The system is however running in the background, I can login to the terminal with Alt-F1.
In my older installation of the original ubuntu-16.04 this has worked without a glitch. My system is a laptop, Yoga Pro 2.
What is wrong and what can I do about it?
Thanks in advance
H

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I was wrong
It was not /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf but /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf that shall contain the line greeter-show-manual-login=true.
Now it works, problem resolved.
H